# Python single thread is slower than two thread in CPU bound

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, gil

I think a thread is faster than two threads in CPU bound.

So, I did an thread experiment.

I executed the CPU bound program 5 times in macOS Mojave Python 3.7.

The code like this.

**1 thread**

```py
import time

COUNT = 50000000


def countdown(n):
    while n>0:
        n -= 1


start = time.time()
countdown(COUNT)
end = time.time()

print('Time taken in seconds -', end - start)

#2.202889919281006
#2.2208809852600098
#2.2509100437164307
#2.1846389770507812
#2.2133240699768066

#avg: 2.214528799
```

**2 threads**

```py
import time
from threading import Thread

COUNT = 50000000


def countdown(n):
    while n > 0:
        n -= 1


t1 = Thread(target=countdown, args=(COUNT // 2,))
t2 = Thread(target=countdown, args=(COUNT // 2,))

start = time.time()

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

end = time.time()

print('Time taken in seconds -', end - start)

#2.1756350994110107
#2.184033155441284
#2.1663358211517334
#2.2320470809936523
#2.2731218338012695

#avg: 2.206234598
```

**4 threads**

```py
# ....

t1 = Thread(target=countdown, args=(COUNT // 4,))
t2 = Thread(target=countdown, args=(COUNT // 4,))
t3 = Thread(target=countdown, args=(COUNT // 4,))
t4 = Thread(target=countdown, args=(COUNT // 4,))

start = time.time()

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()

end = time.time()

print('Time taken in seconds -', end - start)
#2.1956586837768555
#2.218824863433838
#2.3495471477508545
#2.388563871383667
#2.186440944671631

#avg: 2.267807102
```

I think a thread is faster than multi threads because of GIL.(GIL lock & release, thread context switching)

but, 2 threads is faster than a thread. Is wrong my code??

Comment: To time this correctly, each thread should be running N iterations and then you take the resulting time and divide by the number of threads. You are just having each thread doing 1/2 or 1/4 the iterations. It's not exactly comparable. When I do this the more threads you have the slower it goes (slightly, anyway).

Comment: You should do many more tests to have significative numbers since the difference is going to be really really small...

Comment: @Booboo considering that the code is intrinsically a single thread, that is not really relevant...

Comment: A reasonable (and simple) way to make sure you have enough data is to make sure that the average computed with half of the test has the same value...